# I'd like to know the length of the 3D model

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to write a code that allows things to be spaced at regular intervals. The size of the object is not constant, so I want to know the length of x, y, and z of the object. What should I do? Or is there another way to keep it at regular intervals?

I was using scale. But the scale is not the same 3D model's length then I failed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're after the "size" of a mesh, based on it's Axis Aligned Bounding Box (AABB), then you can get a `Renderer`'s `bounds`.

```cs
var mesh = GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh;
Debug.Log(mesh.bounds);
```

You likely want the `mesh.bounds.size.x` value, which is the 'width' of the bounding box.

For the `bounds` struct details, [here's](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Bounds.html) the Unity docs page.